# How to force any application's window to redraw

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am looking for a way to force any window (even the ones where I am not the owner) to redraw. It has to work for all window (cocoa, carbon , ...)

Do you have any pointer to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Why would you need to force another application's window to redraw?

Comment: I've made an application which resize any window but even if the window bounds are set correctly, the content of the window is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You must set this property in the initWithWindow method [self setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
,here the self refers to the window that is being initiated.

Comment: He wants it to work with any window, not only the ones he created.